# Intersection of Sobolev space with the space of continuous functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, approximation-theory

While doing some problems, I came across the space $H=H^1(\Omega) \cap C(\Omega)$, where $\Omega$ is subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$. So far, by definition of these subspaces, We know that none of these are contained in each other and hence $H$ is a proper subspace of both $H^1(\Omega)$ and $C(\Omega)$. Now, most of the results of approximations are for Sobolev spaces.

Q1. Is it possible to develop an analogy of those results for spaces like $H$ which are fairly regular subspaces of Sobolev spaces.

Q2. Do we have some results like embedding or a dense subspace of $H$   which can be used for approximation?

In a nutshell, what all do we know about the space $H$?

Edit: Thanks to Mateusz Kwaśnicki for pointing out that $H$ with the $H^1$ norm is not complete. Here is a classical example.

Define $x_m(t)=0$ for  $t \in [0,\frac{1}{2}]$ and $x_m(t)=1$ for $t \in [a_m,1]$ where $a_m=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{m}$.

$x_m$ is cauchy, but it does not converge in $H$.

Comment: I do not think $H$ is complete with respect to the $H^1$ norm, and consequently $H$ does not seem to be a Hilbert space.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki I think you're right. A basic idea would be to have a cauchy sequence in $H$ which converges in the $H^1$ norm to a discontinuous function.

Comment: The intersection of two Frechet spaces (in this case, one is even Banach) has a canonical Frechet space topology (induced by the sums of continuous seminorms). This topology can be surprisingly complicated. For example, $C(\mathbb R) \cap L^1(\mathbb R)$ is not *distinguished* in the sense of Bourbaki, i.e., its strong dual is not barrelled. As far as I remember, this observation is due to Taskinen.

Comment: As to Q2, $H^1(\Omega)\cap C(\overline{\Omega})$ with $\|\cdot\|_{H^1(\Omega)}+\|\cdot\|_{C(\overline{\Omega})}$ is a Banach space densely embedded in $H$. Another choice would be a Sobolev space with a stronger norm that also embeds in the continuous functions.